# Why don't we need to subscribe to an observable here before converting it to a Promise?

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable

My Service class contains code as :

**Service.ts**

```
//all imports are done
@Injectable()
export class Service{


    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getGoogle():Observable<any> {
        console.log("Inside service");
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    }
}
```

My page component where I make use of service.

**Page.ts**

```
//all imports are done

export class Page1{

constructor(private service: Service, private navCtrl: NavController) { }


 async get() {
    console.log("inside get method");
    const data =  await this.service.getGoogle().toPromise();
      console.log('The response is' , data);
       }

}
```

I have got the required result, but as to understand the concept of Observables and Observer, my Observable should have an Observer sitting to subscribe.Then why should'nt the code const `data = await this.service.getGoogle.subscribe().toPromise()` does not work here and shows error that `property toPromise() does not exists on type Subscription.`

I saw the official resource of [toPromise()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) where I found that it is used with `.just().toPromise()`.Then I found `.just()` API which states that

> The just() method emits its parameter(s) as OnNext notifications, and
>   after that, it emits an OnCompleted notification.

So It is using the features of subscribe here then why it is not used with `.subscribe()`?

Comment: Because `toPromise` is callable on an `Observable` - not a `Subscription` -
 and `toPromise` performs the subscription.

Comment: Also, the link in your question references the RxJS 4 docs. The RxJS 5 -
 which is what's used in Angular - docs are [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the values from an observable, you'll `subscribe()` on the observable. This starts the observable and it will send you the values it produces.

If you rather want to use a `Promise` you can call `toPromise()` on the observable instead. This will make the observable behave like a regular promise.

Under the covers, `toPromise()` calls `subscribe()` on the observable and waits for it to send `complete()`. When the `complete()` signal is received, the promise will resolve the last emitted `next()` signal.

`toPromise()` looks a bit like this:

```
myObservable.takeLast().subscribe(value => resolve(value));
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning what happens under the hood ⭐